# Solving T(n) = 4T(n/2)+n²

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence

I am trying to solve a recurrence using substitution method. The recurrence relation is:

> T(n) = 4T(n/2)+n<sup>2</sup>

My guess is T(n) is Θ(nlogn) (and i am sure about it because of master theorem), and to find an upper bound, I use induction. I tried to show that 
T(n)<=cn<sup>2</sup>logn, but that did not work.

I got T(n)<=cn<sup>2</sup>logn+n<sup>2</sup>. Then I tried to show that, if T(n)<=c<sub>1</sub>n<sup>2</sup>logn-c<sub>2</sub>n<sup>2</sup>, then it is also O(n<sup>2</sup>logn), but that also didn't work and I got T(n)<=c<sub>1</sub>n<sup>2</sup>log(n/2)-c<sub>2</sub>n<sup>2</sup>+n<sup>2</sup>`.

How can I solve this recurrence?

Comment: Should probably be on http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If you're sure about the solution because of master theorem, what exactly is the problem? Master theorem is sufficient (hint: your usage of master theorem is wrong)

Comment: @icepack i need to solve it using substitution method because of my homework question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n2
     = n2 + 4[4T(n/4) + n²/4]
     = 2n2 + 16T(n/4) 
     = ... 
     = k⋅n2 + 4kT(n/2k) 
     = ...
```

The process stops when `2k` reaches `n`.
⇒ `k = log2n`
⇒ `T(n) = O(n2logn)`

Answer (score 6):

[image: diagram of recursive calls]

You can rewrite your equation in a non-recursive form

[image: Non-recursive form of T(n)]

Your recursive equation is pretty simple: every time you expand T(n/2) only one new term appears. So in the non-recursive form you'll have a sum of quadratic terms. You only have to show that A(n) is `log(n)` (I leave it to you as an easy exercise).